# Maintaining product image size and aspect ratio in Weebly

Tags: javascript, html, css, weebly

I am using Weebly to design an eCommerce site. I am having issues with the product element images, The images appear to twice the size from original upload, i do not have access to any other images as the client provided these for me.

I cant seem to get the images to retain the "Natural" size.

I have tried changing what I think is the relevant CSS; and added the following;

```
div.wsite-com-product-images-main-image,.wsite-com-product-images-main image{width: 100% !important;Height: 100% !important;}
```

and

```
.mousetrap{display:none;}
```

Neither appear to be working, it might be a .js query thats running a calculation in order to resize the images but i can find the relevant code.

website is https://www.exoticcarving.com/

example page: https://www.exoticcarving.com/store/p117/Wooden_Bear_%28log%29%2C_handmade_from_suar_wood.html

Would really appreciate some help with this please

Comment: Can you please provide the corresponding HTML snippet (at least the related image tag) - I have an answer but I want to make sure I'm right before I post it.

Comment: <div class="mousetrap" style="background-image:url(&quot;//cdn2.editmysite.com/images/blank.gif&quot;);z-index:2;position:absolute;width:504px;height:1200px;left:0px;top:0px;"></div>

Comment: That's what i think is causing the issue as the width and height in the above differ largely from the images original dimensions.

Comment: I'm afraid your `<div>` example just raised more questions for me. But, it sounds like you've gotten it all sorted out (comment below).

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like this?

```css
.small img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.img-small {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="small">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" />
</div>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" class="img-small" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1000" class="img-small" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/4000x3000" class="img-small" />
```

Setting a width and having the `height` property set to `auto` will scale the image properly. On the other hand, here's a reference to [`object-fit`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) :)

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/VqvLKB).  :)

Comment: I can try those, the problem with these weebly sites is its not always that easy. when i inspect the element on the live site i cant clearly see what is scaling the image.

Comment: SOLVED - Simply added white space to increase the canvass size.